# Data governance Snowflake unload/copy to export data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-governance

I perform data unload form Snowflake to s3 or by using Snowql localy.
I'd like to know if there's any kind of data tracing (for data governance) to always record or tag and save somewhere in Snowflake that a data was unloaded.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY INTO <location>` used for data unloading will leave trace in
[ACCESS_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html):

> This Account Usage view can be used to query the access history of Snowflake objects (e.g. table, view, column) within the last 365 days (1 year).
>
> This view supports write operations of the following type:
>
> Data unloading statements:
>
> - COPY INTO internalStage FROM TABLE
> - COPY INTO externalStage FROM TABLE
> - COPY INTO externalLocation FROM TABLE

and [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html)

---

For data metering perspective [DATA_TRANSFER_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/data_transfer_history.html):

> This Account Usage view can be used to query the history of data transferred from Snowflake tables into a different cloud storage provider’s network (i.e. from Snowflake on AWS, Google Cloud Platform, or Microsoft Azure into the other cloud provider’s network) and/or geographical region within the last 365 days (1 year).

Comment: Thanks, I’ll explore thèse features.